# intering a number after a lettre or a lettre after a number in C

Tags: c, codeblocks

hello i have a task to do the teacher specified that we must do our program with agency list so the first part of the program must be a representing a graph and i did it the second part is that the user enter a letter after a number or a number after a lettre using this graph representation like for example if you enter "4gk2" the output should be "wrong" and if you enter "4f5b" the output should be "correct" can anyone help me with this program am so stuck

here's the the graph i represented in C can anyone complete it please

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int no_nodes;

struct node {
  int data;
  int number;
  char lettre;
  struct node *next;
};

void readAutomat(struct node *tab[]) {
  struct node *newnode;
  int k, data;
  for (int i = 0; i < no_nodes; i++) {
    struct node *last;
    printf("How many nodes are adjacent to %d", i);
    scanf("%d", &k);
    for (int j = 1; j <= k; j++) {
      newnode = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node *));
      printf("Enter the %d neighbour of %d :", j, i);
      scanf("%d", &data);
      newnode->data = data;

      newnode->next = NULL;

      if (tab[i] == NULL) {
        tab[i] = newnode;
      } else {
        last->next = newnode;
      }
      last = newnode;
    }
  }
}

void printAutomat(struct node *tab[]) {
  struct node *temp;
  for (int i = 0; i < no_nodes; i++) {
    temp = tab[i];
    printf("Vertices Adjacent to %d are :", i);
    while (temp != NULL) {
      printf("%d\t", temp->data);
      temp = temp->next;
    }
  }
}

int main() {
  printf("Enter the numbers of nodes");
  scanf("%d", &no_nodes);

  struct node *tab[no_nodes];

  for (int i = 0; i < no_nodes; i++) {
    tab[i] = NULL;
  }
  readAutomat(tab);
  printAutomat(tab);

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is wrong

```
newnode=(struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node *));
```

it creates space for a pointer not for the node struct , you need

```
newnode=(struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
```

or more idiomatically

```
newnode=(struct node *)malloc(sizeof(*newnode));
```

and even better - as per [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc#:~:text=In%20C%2C%20you%20don't,compiler%2C%20a%20cast%20is%20needed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc#:%7E:text=In%20C%2C%20you%20don%27t,compiler%2C%20a%20cast%20is%20needed).

```
newnode=malloc(sizeof(*newnode));
```

Comment: the teacher said that we must use malloc and an adgency list

Comment: @SalimAbdellaoui OK, then ignore the last point, just fix the first error

Comment: no don't cast like that, just `newnode = malloc(sizeof(struct node *));`. See [Do I cast the result of malloc?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/995714)

Comment: @pm100 okay thanks men